# Can std::bind be type checked at compile time?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, typechecking

Is it possible to statically type check the arguments given to `std::bind`? I'm tempted to use it, but it lets me away with almost anything; for example, `std::bind(1,2);` is accepted. Alternatively I could roll my own solution using `std::result_of`.

Comment: I get for: '{ auto x = std::bind(1,2); } error: no matching function for call to 'bind(int, int)', are you sure you are using a proper implementation of it? A lot of things are not checked until 'op()' of it is actually used (since it uses templates). But it shouldn't accept things that a normal call of the function wouldn't also accept.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Which implementation are you using? GCC 4.5.1 and libc++ TOT accept this.

Comment: I am using GCC 4.5.3. `auto qq = std::bind(1,2);` gives me no error.

Comment: @Xeo: For C++11 features I always use some recent svn snapshot. But at least calling x(); afterwards will error out on gcc 4.6. When using C++11 using old versions of gcc like 4.5 is never a good idea.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: The function call operator erroring out is expected. However, `bind` itself should already fail. Seems GCC 4.7's libstdc++ correctly SFINAEs out if the arguments to `bind` aren't callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not yet sure whether or not `bind` could be made to reliably reject such constructs or not.  But if it can, doing so would be an extension.

A `Requires` clause in the standard is telling the client what he has to do to avoid undefined behavior.  It is not telling the vendor what he has to do to be conforming.  So `std::bind(1,2)` is undefined behavior.  It could do anything.  Causing a compile time error would be a nice undefined behavior to have, but is not required.

Comment: Oh! That's good to know. I thought "Require" means a requirement for the implementation.

Comment: @Howard Hinnant: It seems GCC 4.7.0 (20120128) now does reject `std::bind(1,2)`; though it does accept functions alongside too few arguments (though zero arguments does give an error). As you describe though, one compiler vendor may define `bind` one way, and another another. Thanks.